# How to display divs on top of each other?

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I have been trying to figure out how to display my divs side by side, which I managed. The css below works almost perfectly.

```
.awpcp-listing-excerpt {
  width: 40%! important;
  height: 120px! Important;
  float: left! Important;
  margin-right: 15px! Important;
  margin-top: -30px!important;
}

.awpcp-listing-excerpt-inner {
  margin-right: 50px !important;
  margin: auto !important;
  margin-left: -50px !important;
  width: 140px !important;
  height: 300px !important;
  margin-top: -140px !important;
  box-shadow: 0 8px 16px #888888!important;
}

.awpcp-listing-excerpt-content {
  display: none;
}

.awpcp-listing-excerpt-thumbnail {
  margin-top: 40px! Important;
  margin-left: -7px!important;
}

.awpcp-listing-title {
  margin-top: 140px! Important;
  font-size: 10px;
  text-align: left! Important;
  background-color: yellow;
}

.awpcp-listing-excerpt-extra {
  margin-top: -100px !important;
  margin-left: 20px !important;
}
```

The problem is, when i come to display a third ad, to repeat the current pattern of two ads side by side, it doesn't work. Please see page for example. https://adsler.co.uk/browse-adsler/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hello Sta and welcome to Stack Overflow. There are several problems with your code that cause the overlapping:

- not clearing floated elements (`float: left;`)
- giving fixed width and height
- giving a width in percent that won't allow three columns (ads) next to one another
- using negative margins (`margin-top: -140px !important;`)

It's kind of hard to give you a simple answer that will solve all your problems.

Here are some hints:

- When using floated elements inside a container, use a `<br style="clear:both">` to make sure that height and width calculation are corrected. Floated elements are removed from the document flow, causing its parent containers to not take the height and width of the floated children into account
- instead of a fixed width, use (if required) a `min-width: 100px;` (100 just as a sample value) to allow more elements to be in a line. Best would be to use [flex box](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) along with `flex-wrap: wrap;` to define columns of data

Mixing rules like `position: relative;`, `float: left;` and `margin-top: -140px;` is often a sign for a poor GUI design. I would recommend to first design just one box holding all the information with as few CSS as possible and in a second step check how several of these boxes fit next to one another.

**Update 1:**

To give you an idea of how it could look like, check this [Codepen](https://codepen.io/AlexWayhill/pen/PvNxbj). Basically we set the listings to occupy 20% of the total width but expend to the available width in case there is room left.

Here's the remaining CSS I used:

```css
.awpcp-listings {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.awpcp-listing-excerpt 
{
  min-width: 20%;
  margin-right: 15px;
  box-shadow: 0 8px 16px #888888 !important;
  border-style: solid;
  color: grey;
  border-radius: 4px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  flex-grow: 2;
}

.awpcp-listing-excerpt-inner {
  min-width: 140px;
  min-height: 200px;
}
.awpcp-listing-excerpt-content {
  display: none;
}

.awpcp-listing-title {
  font-size: 10px;
  padding: 5px;
  text-align: left;
  background-color: yellow;
}
.awpcp-listing-excerpt-extra {
  margin-left: 20px;
}
```

BTW, always try to avoid `!important` as this makes overwriting impossible. Instead try to be more explicit in your rule definition.

Short example:

You have a `<div class="special">This is red</div>` and matching CSS rules to color a DIV in yellow which would be:

```css
div {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

but as you want it to be red instead, you can be more precise and add the rule:

```css
div.special {
  background-color: red;
}
```

If you see that one element is not following your CSS rule, use the Developer Tools (F12 in most browsers) and click on "Inspect element", then choose the element that needs to be altered. You will then see all CSS rules applying to that object and then match your CSS rules to overwrite these rules by using the exact same rule. This requires your CSS file to be loaded *AFTER* the prior file was loaded.

**Update 2:**

First, change the following CSS rules to have your items show up in columns. All commented rules mean that these should be removed from the stylesheet.

```
/* Inline #51 | https://adsler.co.uk/browse-adsler/ */

.awpcp-listing-excerpt {
  min-width: 32%;
  /* float: left; */
  /* flex-grow: 2; */
}

.awpcp-listing-excerpt-extra {
  /* height: 50%; */
}

/* awpcpstyle.css | https://adsler.co.uk/wp-content/plugins/another-wordpress-classifieds-plugin/resources/css/awpcpstyle.css?ver=3.9.5 */

.awpcp-listing-excerpt-small .awpcp-listing-excerpt-thumbnail, .awpcp-listing-excerpt-medium .awpcp-listing-excerpt-thumbnail {
  /* float: left; */
}

.displayaditemseven {
  /* width: 100%; */
}

.awpcp-listing-excerpt-medium .awpcp-listing-excerpt-thumbnail {
  /* width: auto; */
}

.displayaditemsodd {
  /* width: 100%; */
}

/* so-css-shapely.css | https://adsler.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/so-css/so-css-shapely.css?ver=1557474259 */

.awpcp-listing-excerpt-extra {
  /* height: 0px; */
}
```

In a second step, add a [media query](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media/width) to your stylesheet to only show two columns when the screen size is less then 900 pixels.

```
@media (max-width: 900px) {
  .awpcp-listing-excerpt {
    min-width: 46%;
  }
}
```

Comment: That's great. And you're obviously very knowledgeable. Thanks for your time. I'm just learning all this stuff though, so how would you edit my current css so as to allow for what I need? Negative values are also the only option too. Positive didn't work, believe it or not. I'm sure what you said is correct, so I'll mark it as such, but would you mind giving me a hint of how to work with what I have to make the changes I need? Thanks.

Comment: What i mean is, how would you edit the above html css to make it work?

Comment: @Sta thanks for accepting my answer, even if it was just hints. I will set up a Codepen to show you an alternative but this will take some minutes. Will notify you in another comment when I'm done.

Comment: In had also thought to use an @media query to solve the three or more side by side issue simply dividing the div onto three or more parts 33% 33% 33% etc...

Comment: @Sta I added an example and more hints below it to give you a direction. Hope this helps!

Comment: Thats great. Thanks.

Comment: Im actually on my mobile. I designed the whole site on an old Huawei.

Comment: @Sta really? I couldn't even think of designing sites on my mobile and I guess I'll stick to my PC ;-)

Comment: :-) just one more question. Now that they're on top of each other, is there a simple trick to get therm side by side too? See page: https://adsler.co.uk/browse-adsler/

Comment: Say two by two mobile, 5 by 5 desktop?

Comment: @Sta I will check your code later today and give you feedback.

Comment: @Sta just added some more style changes and comments to my answer, see if that helps you.

Comment: Thanks. Brill. So the text in grey should be removed?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/193186/discussion-between-sascham78-and-sta).

Comment: Ok. Posted in chat. Thanks

Comment: @SaschaM78Thanks so much for your time. The code works, I don't know how you did it but it works. The only thing I'm trying to figure out is, why it doesn't display two by two grid in mobile portrait, but does in mobile landscape.... otherwise brilliant. Thanks.

Comment: @Sta the media query (last part of my answer) seems to be missing from your code. There are also a lot of problems with your CSS e.g. the class name prefix "." is missing from the CSS rules (`wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-submit` should be `.wpcf7-form-control .wpcf7-submit`, otherwise this rule would apply to `<wpcf7-form-control><wpcf7-submit></wpcf7-submit></wpcf7-form-control>`).